# ADO.Entity Model with simple membership tables?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ado.net, simplemembership

I am new to both MVC and the simple membership that comes with ASP.NET.

I have been following tutorials and I have been able to create the Simple membership tables to work in a custom db along with my own tables.

I ran into a problem when I tried to use the ADO.Entity Model to create classes so i could access the database data. When i tried to run the application after creating the entity models i got an error. I think it is because the ADO.Entity Model created classes with the same name as classes all ready in the app???

```
    Error   1   Missing partial modifier on declaration of type 'MvcApplication5.Models.UserProfile'; another partial declaration of this type exists   C:\Users\user\Desktop\MvcApplication5\MvcApplication5\Models\AccountModels.cs   22  18  MvcApplication5
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

SimpleMembership uses EF code-first so you do not need to create the classes, they are already created by the T4 Internet Template.  The class that represents the UserProfile exists in the file referenced in your error message. You are getting an error message because you are trying to create a duplicate of the class that already exists. Take a look at this [article on how to customize SimpleMembership](http://kevin-junghans.blogspot.com/2013/01/seeding-customizing-aspnet-mvc.html).